# Actionscript, getting stage.stageWidth after an orientation event

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am detecting an orientation change using

```
flash.events.StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING
```

Each time orientation occurs two events occur,

```
event.beforeOrientation
event.afterOrientation
```

However, after event.afterOrientation the stage.stageWidth property remains the same.

Is it possible to detect a orientation complete event, so I can then get the new stage width property.

I am hoping such an event exists as otherwise I think I must detect the orientation state and work out if the width and height need to be switched. But I do not like this solution because stage.stageWidth does get updated shortly after event.afterOrientation occurs, so I would need to track this.

Comment: I use **stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize)** and it never fails me in terms of correct stage width and height.

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect, I guess I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: That is what you did : )))