# Actionscript, why does Event.RESIZE occur twice on orientation change?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Take the below simple example

```
    public function test2()
    {

        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize);
    }

    private function resize(event:Event):void {
        trace('resize');
    }
```

On orientation change, via Ctrl L, the resize event is called twice. Why is this so?

The first resize occurs after both orientation change begins and end, so I think it should occur once.

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, because I am re-positioning a large number of display objects based on resize and this is occurring twice for no reason.

Comment: Okey, there **is** a problem. Did you look into stage width and height on both events? Are they identical? Or the first one is identical to the previous state, then the second one represent the actual changes? Or maybe some other behavior?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing stage height and width.  Both are identical for each resize event, they are of course reversed prior to resize. My code above was simply a new flash builder project with just the event listener added. Then I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913432/how-to-prevent-event-resize-to-trigger-twice-on-displaystate-change-to-full-scre and found that the issue only occurs in the debugger/simulator.

Comment: So, there is **no** problem in the first place. Then, just in case, you might want to save the current width and height after realigning your UI, so, if they are identical on subsequent call, just do nothing.

Comment: Is it for mobile? If so you should try the StageOrientationEvent  instead

Comment: @Philarmon it is, but I did use StageOrientationEvent before see here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408103/actionscript-getting-stage-stagewidth-after-an-orientation-event - and it actually did not behave as desired, as I need the new stage size.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only occurs in the debugger.